# How to access nodejs config

Tags: node.js, proxy, environment-variables

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Is how I set a proxy for my node installation. How can I access this configured proxy from inside my nodejs application?

Comment: if you hack the npm configuration files, then yes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could call `npm config list` as a subprocess which will return all configurations, similar to this one:

```
; cli configs
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"

; userconfig /home/username/.npmrc
email = "name@domain.com"
username = "name"

; node bin location = /home/name/apps/nvm/v0.10.7/bin/node
; cwd = /home/name/subfolder
; HOME = /home/name
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

Use `npm config ls -l` to get a full list, which includes the default config settings.